# Check equality of two axes in multidiimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am given a 3-dimensional shape(n,m,k) numpy array. I'd like to view this as a 2-dimensional matrix containing vectors, i.e. a nxm matrix with a vector of size k. I'd now like to check for two such arrays of shape (n,m,k) wheter entry (x,y,:) in the first array is equal to (x,y,:) in the second array. Is there a method to do this in numpy without using loops?

I'd thought about something like A == B conditioned on the first and second axis.

Comment: So `A.shape = (n, m, k)` and  `B.shape = (x, y, z)`... Why not do: `A.shape[:2] == B.shape[:2]` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a condition, and `ndarray.all` together with `axis`:

```
a = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
b = np.zeros_like(a)
b[0,1,2] = a[0,1,2]
b[1,2,0] = a[1,2,0]
b[2,1,:] = a[2,1,:] # set to the same 3-vector at n=2, m=1

(a == b).all(axis=2) # check whether all elements of last axis are equal
# array([[False, False, False],
#        [False, False, False],
#        [False,  True, False]])
```

As you can see, for `n=2` and `m=1` we get the same 3-vector in `a` and `b`.